# How to inject a ConfigurationProperties to s Configuration class with Scala

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-boot

When writing a spring-boot app with Scala, I get a problem of how to inject a ConfigurationProperties to s Configuration class.

I tried the code like:

```
@Configuration
class Config @Autowired() (var properties: MessagePathProperties)
```

but an exception occurred:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: configuration.Config$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8875845.<init>()
```

I also tried the code like:

```
@Configuration
class Config {
     @Autowired private var properties: MessagePathProperties = _
    ...
}
```

The app itself starts normally, but I found `properties` is null in Config.

Meanwhile, I tried to inject the properties in a service class like:

```
@Service
class MessageService @Autowired() (var properties: MessagePathProperties)
```

and the `properties` works properly in the MessageService class.

So, I don't know what is the difference between @Configuration and @Service that makes the different effect.

BTW, here's my app class as reference:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class ScalaServiceApplication

object Launch extends App {
  SpringApplication.run(classOf[ScalaServiceApplication], args :_ *)
}
```

Comment: Put spring into garbage bag and use scala implicits insead

Comment: Thanks you reply, Igor. But would you provide some code please? I'm a freshman to scala...

Comment: At first read Martin Odersky, Lex Spoon Programming Scala, about implicts. This featuere of scala language is meant to be hard to undestand, but very powerful, and replaces all "DI" frameworks out of box, without any annotations.
2. Example

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you to use implicit parameters insead of spring.

Recomend you to use implicits insead
Assume you need to inject logger into worker, and there could be differend kinds of loggers:

```
case class Worker(in: String)(implicit logger: Logger) {
  def work(): Unit = {
    logger.log(s"working on $in")
    // doing some work here
  }
}

trait Logger {
  def log(message: String)
}

case class ConsoleLogger() extends Logger {
  override def log(message: String): Unit = {
    // just prints the message
    println(message)
  }
}

object MyApp extends App {
  implicit val logger: Logger = ConsoleLogger()
  // logger in current scope (ConsoleLogger) would be injected into worker
  val worker = Worker("some work")
  worker.work()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the case and how to resolve it finally.

Actually, I also create a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in the `Config` class, but there's a warming message at console,

```
@Bean method Config.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
```

So, I just move the method into a scala object like:

```
object Config {
  @Bean def propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer: PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
}
```

Thus, everything works fine.